# loading multiple xml tags in the same JQGrid

Tags: jquery, xml, jqgrid

my xml file is something like this :

```
<abc>
   <a>
      <item>
         <name>...</name>
        <cost>....</cost>
      </item>
      .
      .
      .  
      .
   </a>
   <b>
      <item>
         <name>...</name>
         <cost>....</cost>
      </item>
      .
      .
      .  
      .
   </b>
```

I want to load the values of both tag  and  [without changing both tag names the same], on a jqgrid. when i use xmlReader twice it only loads the later root values..... anyone has any idea how to load both the tags ????

Comment: where is your jqgrid codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most easy way to read such XML data would be to specify `xmlReader` like following

```js
xmlReader : {
    root: "abc",
    row: "a>item,b>item",
    repeatitems: false
}
```

In more complex cases you can use functions inside of `xmlReader`:

```js
xmlReader : {
    root: "abc",
    row: function (obj) {
        return $("a>item,b>item", obj);
    },
    repeatitems: false
}
```

or

```js
xmlReader : {
    root: "abc",
    row: function (obj) {
        return $("a>item", obj).add("b>item", obj);
    },
    repeatitems: false
}
```

[The corresponding demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Ambkrish.htm) read the following XML

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<abc>
   <a>
      <item>
         <name>Name A1</name>
         <cost>123</cost>
      </item>
      <item>
         <name>Name A2</name>
         <cost>234</cost>
      </item>
   </a>
   <b>
      <item>
         <name>Name B1</name>
         <cost>345</cost>
      </item>
      <item>
         <name>Name B2</name>
         <cost>456</cost>
      </item>
   </b>
</abc>
```

and displays the results as

[image]

It uses the code

```js
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url: "Ambkrish.xml",
    datatype: "xml",
    gridview: true,
    autoencode: true,
    pager: "#pager",
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 50],
    viewrecords: true,
    height: "auto",
    xmlReader : {
        root: "abc",
        row: "a>item,b>item",
        repeatitems: false
    },
    colModel:[
        { name: "name", label: "Name" },
        { name: "cost", label: "Cost", formatter: "integer", sorttype: "integer", align: "right" }
    ],
    cmTemplate: {width: 200},
    loadonce: true
});
```